# It is true, for some $N$ constant, that $x^{p}\leq Nx^{\alpha p}$ for $\alpha>1,\ p\geq 1$?

Tags: inequality, lp-spaces

I know that $(x+y)^p\leq 2^p(x^p+y^p)$ for all $x,y\geq 0$ and $p\geq 0$.

Let $\alpha>1$ and $p\geq 1$.
Exists a constant $C$ such that, for all $x>0,\  x^{p}\leq N x^{\alpha p}$?

If $x\geq 1$, then $x^{p}\leq x^{\alpha p}$ is holds.
If $x<1$, Is it true?

I try something like this
$x^p\leq (x+1)^p\leq (x+1)^{\alpha p}\leq 2^p(x^{\alpha p}+1)$
but obviously it doesn't work since there is 1 ...

Answer (score 1):

This is a question but I hope it will suffice as an answer: What is $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{p(1-\alpha)}$?

> Recall $p(1-\alpha) < 0$.

Comment: That limit is 0. But, it would only serve me for values ​​close to the origin.

Comment: In the specific instance where $p=2$ and $\alpha = \frac 32$ you are claiming that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{-1} = 0$.

Comment: My mistake. I should have said "is $\infty$"

Comment: There you go. There is no upper bound $N$.